# Hyper V security permission error with Windows Phone 8 emulator

Tags: emulation, windows-phone-8, hyper-v

I'm having trouble when booting up the Windows Phone 8 emulator. I'm seeing the following message

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHqGT.png

I followed the guide on the [Windows Phone Emulator troubleshooting site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (it's halfway down the page) and it doesn't work. I have administrator access to my computer. I do not see a Local Hyper-V administrators group in the Console Manager. Any ideas?

EDIT: To clarify, I can fire up the emulator, it's just that this pop-up comes up every time requesting me to add myself to the local hyper-v security group.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Did you try this link [Add a user account to a group](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Add-a-user-account-to-a-group) ?

And Restart the system after following that process.

Comment: Which group would I be adding to? I tried adding to Administrators (I was already in it) and rebooting and it didn't help. I couldn't find any Security group or any mention of Hyper-V

Answer (score 3):

I Just Open visual studio as "Run as Administrator". and it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem - 
this solved it -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/01/17/allowing-non-administrators-to-control-hyper-v.aspx

cheers.

Comment: I tried following the instructions but it seems like I'm locked from step 11. I don't see "Assign users and groups" under the action menu